# Is the phrase 'Sociable at heart' meaningful?

Tags: phrases

I am trying to find a description of someone who is really sociable. Can I say 'Sociable at heart' to add some exaggeration?

Comment: If you list the actual activities that show they are sociable, that's better than claiming it with an exaggerated label.

Comment: I'd use 'sociable at heart' to describe someone who was perhaps very reserved in company but still enjoyed it. So people might assume they weren't sociable even though they are, at heart.

Comment: @Spagirl -- your totally right interpretation validates the question itself -- some people are too shy/ formal/ reserved to be very sociable in effect, but they are *sociable at heart.*

Comment: OP please note: Many an objective person like @Yosef Baskin would prefer to be given information that proves an assertion (as in, how/why do you claim that somebody is sociable) so if you do assert they are 'sociable at heart' you would need to back it up with more information, as in "Rupert appears shy/ formal/ reserved if not positively unfriendly, but I know he's ***sociable at heart*** because *I've seen him relax, unwind and really enjoy himself with family or trusted friends* -- it's just that he freezes up & withdraws into himself in the presence of colleagues/ acuaintances/ strangers."

Comment: Note too that a statement like 'sociable at heart' is no exaggeration, but rather, an accurate description of an [introvert.](http://elitedaily.com/life/culture/means-social-introvert/986630/) An introverted person isn't really unsociable, but generally prefers the company of family and/or trusted friends; gets exhausted in the presence of a lot of acquaintances and strangers; and prefers to spend a lot of time alone. The word 'introvert' is still mainly used to connote 'inward-looking', but a simple google search throws up much to suggest introverts are, rather amazingly, *sociable at heart!*

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I believe "at heart" should be used in a sentence:
"Sure, he beats his wife, but he's a good guy at heart."
Here, "at heart" doesn't exaggerate the fact that the guy is good. Rather it suggests that the guy is good despite appearances.

Comment: OK, but can you also explain, how does that relate to 'sociable?'